# I've attached my code. Please review it and tell me the reason of the error. Explain it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, error-handling

#### My code

```
x = 10
def fun():
    x = x + 2
    print(x)
fun()
print(x)
```

#### And the output error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass global `x` in the def fun() as no variable named x is assigned in fun(). Here is the code:

```
x = 10
def fun():
    global x
    x = x + 2
    print(x)
fun()
print(x)
```

#### Output

```
>>> 12
>>> 12
```

OR

You can also simply pass an argument, but this makes a difference in the values of x:

```
x = 10
def fun(x):
    x = x + 2
    print(x)
fun(x)
print(x)
```

#### Output

```
>>> 12
>>> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give x as the parameter to the function. That's why.

```
x = 10
def fun(x):
    x = x + 2
    print(x)
fun()
print(x)
```

Comment: See it's my choice to choose what type and how I will define a function. I can define a function with no arguments...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `x`, that you're trying modify in the function `fun()`, is of global scope. Hence, you can't access it inside the function like that. However, you can use:

```
x = 10
def fun():
    global x
    x = x + 2
    print(x)
fun()
print(x)
```

Appending `global x`, will allow the function to modify the variable `x` which is in global scope.